# Invalid screen detect by xrandr

Tags: display, screen, x11, xquartz

I using MacBook Air M1. When I run xrandr, output is:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 525, current 5760 x 1956, maximum 5760 x 1980
default connected 5760x1956+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1152x720      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1650x1050     60.00  
   2048x1280     60.00  
   2560x1600     60.00  
   5760x1956      1.00* 
   5760x1980      2.00
```

But I use 4 monitors - 3 x 1920x1080 and one retina 2560x1600 in below configuration

[image]

How can I repair xrandr? XFreeRdp use xrandr to detect screens in multiscreen mode and this is some issue to run XFreeRdp session only on 2 or 3 screens.

Comment: So it detects one very wide screen (3 times 1920) instead of three screens. How (technically) are the three external monitors connected to the MBA?

Comment: Screens are connected by 2 DisplayLink chips (one single DisplayLink adapter, and one dock station with 2x DP (displaylink) + 1x HDMI(thunderbolt alt mode), audio, ethernet, etc. etc)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer is "write your own X server and implement this differently".  This is not a bug, it's how Apple has chosen to implement the RandR protocol.  It's not quite a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/598137/xrandr-on-osx-not-recognising-screens), but you can see the answer on that one also saying that `xrandr` simply doesn't work this way on macOS.

Comment: In linked topic I don't see anything about implementing RandR protocol. Maybe we could change xrandr codebase to detect screens in right way and sent pull request? But I'm not sure this is problem randr or deeper - in XQuartz? And how apple now give api to detect screens? Other apps can do it, so it's possible workaround I think.

Comment: `xrandr` is a client program that speaks the `RandR` protocol to the X server it's connected to, which in this case is XQuartz.  The relevant fix would be to send a pull request to https://www.xquartz.org to have that X server talk to a macOS API, probably [`NSScreen.screens`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsscreen/1388393-screens?language=objc), to enumerate and return macOS displays as X displays.

Comment: Also… if you want a free RDP client for macOS, maybe just check out https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12 ?  That will probably work better than trying to use X11 software on macOS, which is, sadly, an increasingly rickety proposition as time goes on.

Comment: Thanks for info, I will debug XQuartz. Unfortunately I can't use RDP client from MS. In MS client I can use one screen, or all screens. I have 4 and sometimes 6 screens. I want to run RDP session on 4 screens, and on 5 I want run MSTeams, an on 6 screen Apple Music and CCTV client. Only XFreeRdp can run RDP session on chosen screens.